# JSON.parse from php script

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get some JSON from a php script. Bit it is failing when I try to parse it.

In the php script I use json_encode($result) and in the jQuery part I use this code:

```
complete: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                var arr = [];
                for(var x in parsed){ arr.push(parsed[x]);}
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            }
```

When I log response in the console I get this:

```
 Object { readyState=4, responseText="{"personeelsNummer":"1",...oonplaats":"Meerhout"}0", status=200, meer...}
```

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: it looks like your json is inside of `response.responseText`. Not sure why there is 0 at the end though.

Comment: First try add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax; Second, use `success` and not `complete` to receive the json already parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:

Ensure your `$.ajax` has `dataType: "json"` as part of the settings.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    //other settings
});
```

Second:

You are using `complete`. On `complete`, the arguments are `jqXHR` and `textStatus`. Therefore, it's not parsed there, it's the entire xhr object.

For that you have to use `success`. There the arguments are `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR`, and if you used the dataType as I told (and your JSON is valid), it `data` will be your already-parsed json.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    //other settings
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            //my awesome parsed json it's on 'data'
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //my awful json which failed to parse, and I can know the error on 'errorThrown'
    }
});
```

Comment: @stijn26 because your JSON is malformed. See the responseText you posted: `{"personeelsNummer":"1",...oonplaats":"Meerhout"}0"`. There's a `0` after `Meerhout` which shouldn't be there. That's why I added the  `error`, so you can use the `errorThrown` to see the error message.

Comment: Ah okay, but how does the 0 get there? I'm not using 0's anywhere

Comment: @stijn26 No idea. It's not something being added by jQuery, is part of your service's response. Try access the URL you are testing directly on the browser tab and see the response.

Comment: I needed to add 'die()' to the end of the php script :D

Comment: @stijn26 cool, so probl the plugin was adding more stuff later. Now the success/error might work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
```

`response` is an object with more properties than just the text content from the server request.

Comment: Using this now:
complete: function(response){
                var arr = [];
                for(var x in response){ arr.push(response[x]);}
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            }

This gets me following error: TypeError: a.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: the first answer was wrong in your context. i edited it. use `JSON.parse(response.responseText)` or `success` event without parsing.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 66 of the JSON data.
Because of the 0 behind the JSON, no idea why its there though.

Comment: maybe you send this "0" from php. is the zero there when you open the json url in the browser aswell?

Comment: How can I open the JSON url in the browser? Do you mean the php script? It's not there

Comment: yes, the php script that returns json. what is it's url. i will test.

Comment: http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/plugins/FixFormData/getuser.php
Do you get any wiser from this?

Comment: this page does not return json: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function add_action() in <b>/home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnaerts.be/public_html/test/wp-content/plugins/FixFormData/getuser.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />`

Comment: Yeah its in a wordpress plugin so I wouldn't know how you can let it return something this way. But I can see the answer it gives via firebug, and the 0 is also present there

Comment: I needed to add 'die()' to the end of the php script :D